# How to make cross validation data set

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark, apache-spark-ml

I want to conduct cross validation on machine learning algorithms but want to check the model estimate for each iterations. Do you know if there is a function available on pyspark that allows me to create k-fold data set?

I need that k-fold data set to run each algorithm and output the variable estimates. For example, if it is 5-fold CV, I need to have 5 data sets ready for me to run against algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

In case you only need the fitted models and if you are using Spark ML, then you could use the CrossValidator and set `collectSubModels` to `true`. For example:

```
cv = (CrossValidator()
  .setEstimator(<your_estimator>)
  .setEstimatorParamMaps(<your_param_maps>)
  .setEvaluator(<your_evaluator>)
  .setCollectSubModels(True))

cv_model = cv.fit(dataset)
models = cv_model.subModels
```

If you really want to have access to the datasets yourself, then the above approach will not work. You could write a function yourself that loops `n_folds` times over your dataset, and based on a random number selects the data for that fold. An example of how that could look like is the following:

```
import uuid
from pyspark.sql.functions import rand


def create_folds(df, n_folds, seed):
  h = 1.0 / n_folds
  rand_column_name = f"{uuid.uuid1()}_rand"
  df = df.select("*", rand(seed).alias(rand_column_name)

  result = []
  for k in range(n_folds):
    lb = k * h
    up = (k + 1) * h
    condition = (df[rand_column_name] >= lb) & (df[rand_column_name] < ub)
    train_df = df.filter(~condition).drop(rand_column_name)
    validation_df = df.filter(condition).drop(rand_column_name)
    result.append((train_df, validation_df))
  return result

datasets = create_folds(df, 5, 10)
# Accessing the first fold
train_df1 = datasets[0][0]
validation_df1 = datasets[0][1]
```

Note that in the above example that you are not getting 5 datasets but 10 datasets. This is because for each fold, we are creating a training and validation dataset.

A former colleague of mine actually wrote a [nice blog post](https://www.timlrx.com/2018/04/08/creating-a-custom-cross-validation-function-in-pyspark/) about how you can make your own PySpark CrossValidator class using the approach above.